# How to set up your visual studio settings to run multiple c files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up Visual Studio Code to function with multiple .c and header files.
I installed the C/C++, Code Rrunner and the C/C++ Makefile Project plug in.
The code works just fine when I compile only one file.
Here are the errors it gives me:

```
PS C:\Users\rlung\OneDrive\Documenti\VisualStudioCode> cd "c:\Users\rlung\OneDrive\Documenti\VisualStudioCode\src\" ; if ($?) { gcc ex_02.c -o ex_02 } ; if ($?) { .\ex_02 }
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `HTcreate'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `HTinsert'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to `HTprintStructure'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `HTprintStructure'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `HTdestroy'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `listCreate'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rlung\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0P4dqJ.o:ex_02.c:(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `HTinsert'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\rlung\OneDrive\Documenti\VisualStudioCode\src>
```

As you can see it says "undefined reference to..." for every function of the other files i use.
I found lots of answers to this problem and tried everything but I still can't manage to make it work.
I am on windows 10 using mingw64 and this are my .json files.

---

tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
    }
]
```

}

I even try to indicate where my header files are in the c_cpp_properties.json.

This is what my Visual Studio Code project looks like:

[image]

I tried to change up a bit the tasks.json, in particular the "${file}" string after "-g", but nothing. I also tried compiling and linking everything by hand using: gcc ex_02.c -0 ex_02 -c //for every c file I have and then i linked them togheter using: gcc -o myprog ex_02.o //all object file created before, It works this way but I would like to use code runner and not worry about writing all this stuff everytime, how can i accomplish it?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy it verbatim. And to make analysis possible, please show us the _complete_ output of the build. Especially the command is important.

Comment: Copied the text directly from the output, what do you mean by "command"?

Comment: The first line of your output is the command to compile, this is what I meant. (There is more in the line, but it is not executed because of the link error.)

Comment: The command to compile and link is just `gcc ex_02.c -o ex_02`, and it does not match the JSON files. Additionally, it seems as if the missing functions are in another module or library, and this is not provided in the command. To let others help you, I cannot because I don't use VSC, you might want to add exactly _how_ you try to build and run.